# Spring Security - Simple CORS authentication error

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

I have a spring based application using Spring Security to handle the authentication. Our application needs to provide support for simple Cross Origin Resource Sharing, the application can be accessed from 'http://myApplication.myDomain.net' and 'http://www.myApplication.myDomain.net', I've configured my Simple CORS Filter to allow multiple request origins,so these two domains will have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin request response header. The issue is that when I access the application from this domain 'http://myApplication.myDomain.net' is works perfectly, but when I try to access the application from here 'http://www.myApplication.myDomain.net' I'm only able to log in but the inmediate following request to display the main dash-board gets a 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
I'm using AngularJS and grunt, from Angular all requests are made to http://myApplication.myDomain:8087/api/....

My question is, how can I add to support to both domains? Why the log ing request works but any further actions are forbiden?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an interceptor

```
public class CorsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

 public static final String CREDENTIALS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";
 public static final String ORIGIN_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
 public static final String METHODS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
 public static final String HEADERS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
 public static final String MAX_AGE_NAME = "Access-Control-Max-Age";
 public static final String REQUEST_ORIGIN_NAME = "Origin";

private final List<String> origins;

    public CorsInterceptor(List<String> origins) {
        this.origins = origins;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        response.setHeader(CREDENTIALS_NAME, "true");
        response.setHeader(METHODS_NAME, "GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        response.setHeader(HEADERS_NAME, "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        response.setHeader(MAX_AGE_NAME, "3600");

        String origin = request.getHeader(REQUEST_ORIGIN_NAME);
        if (origins.contains(origin)) {
            response.setHeader(ORIGIN_NAME, origin);
            return true; // Proceed
        }

        return false;
   }

}
```

**in Config**

```
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CorsInterceptor(Arrays.asList("'http://myApplication.myDomain.net","http://www.myApplication.myDomain.net")));
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, makes sense to me, I've implemented your sugestion and seems to be working on development environment, however I have to try it on production environment to mark it as the correct answer, for now is an +1 up-vote from me. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunely this didn't fix my issue, I finally found the issue which was related to the CSRF tokens that use the application to handle authentication, for some reason the CSRF token cookie is not being set for cross domains even tough I'm setting the cookie domain explicitly, only for local domain, the login request is of course filtered-out from the CSRF filters. How ever this solution es very effective if you require a per-request interceptor.